# How to use strings for OSLogMessage?

Tags: swift

Given the following two lines, XCode is showing an error for the second line saying `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'OSLogMessage'`.

```swift
logger.info("Device found:")
logger.info(String(describing: device))
```

Can someone please explain why this error is shown? In both cases, the parameter is of type String. (I guess)

Currently, I fix this by using string interpolation. But this does not feel right. Is there a better way than:

```swift
logger.info("\(String(describing: device))")
```

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675874/xcode-12-and-oslog-os-log-wrapping-oslogmessage-causes-compile-error-argumen might be helful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What I get from this post is that interpolation seems to be something special in Swift? It says that OSLog received interpolation support. Coming from languages like TypeScript or C#, there interpolation is supported by any String. But in Swift it seems one has to enable this? So for me, a String is just a String. With or without interpolation. Wether created via "..." or String(...). This is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

The (surprising, perhaps) answer is that OSLog doesn't allow an arbitrary string to be logged for privacy reasons. It's not a language limitation but a policy to control the availability of user data in logs.